# Argument type Number is not assignable to parameter type String|Function

Tags: javascript, webstorm

```
var str = name.toUpperCase();
var ch = new Array();
ch = str.split('');

for(var i=0;i<7;i++)
{
  if(ch = null) {
    result_code.replace(
      pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString(),
      "FFFF");
  } else {
    var temp = parseInt(ch[i]);
    var temp_integer = 64;
    if(temp<=122 & temp>=97) {
      var pos = i+1;
      result_code.replace(
        pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString(),
        (temp - temp_integer)+40);
    }
  }
}
```

This code is creating the error at this line `result_code.replace(pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString()+pos.toString(), (temp - temp_integer)+40);`.

The underlined information is this section `(temp - temp_integer)+40`.

The error shown is `Argument type Number is not assignable to parameter type String|Function`.

What is wrong with this code? I am using WebStorm. I am likely just making a dumb mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to repeat a string you can do `new Array(5).join(pos)`

Comment: @elclanrs: `a..z`, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Put a `+ ""` after the + 40

Comment: check your condition and find other reconcilation `if(ch = null )`

Comment: `if (ch = null)` is always falsy (you wanted `ch === null`?). And you're calling `replace` multiple times but never do anything with the returned result - notice that JS strings are immutable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `replace` method accepts a string or a function as second parameter. Turn your value into a string: `((temp - temp_integer)+40).toString()`.

Comment: Thanks!! Can't believe I missed that. Will set accepted answer once it lets me.

Comment: @torazaburo: Are you using Webstorm?

Answer (score 3):

```
(temp - temp_integer)+40
```

is a numeric value and `replace` wants a string. Just use:

```
(temp - temp_integer)+40+""
```

assuming that you want the string representation of the number (eg, `65` becomes `"65"`). If you want the *character* at that code point (`65` becomes `"A"`), you should look into using [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: Thanks!! Can't believe I missed that. Sadly, accepted answer goes to @Guffa (he was first, sorry)

Comment: _Damn_ those eight seconds :-)